# Icons got replaced by other icons if i kept my UWP application idle for some time and open it again

Tags: c#, image, uwp

I am developing a UWP application. The problem i am facing is when i minimize my app for some time
( say 15 min) and again open it , some of its icon get distorted or completely replaced by other icon.
For example:

[image: replaced icon]

In the above image you can see circle icon is replaced by attachment icon please help.
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhYgj.png)

In the second example we can see  icons getting distorted.
Below is the Xaml:

```
<Image Width="25" Source="{Binding MachineStatus}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
```

Source is with the property so below is the body of  property

```
 public string MachineStatus
    {
        get
        {
            if (SystemCondition == "0")
                return "/Assets/Images/syscond0.png";
            else if (SystemCondition == "1")
                return "/Assets/Images/syscond1.png";
            else return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please click on replaced icon to view image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more details on how you added the icons and what they are supposed to look like. Code is always welcome.

Comment: Please add the xaml content or code behind, and the better is provide [mcve] for us.

Comment: @soumer Thanks for responding . I have added whatever info i can add. One more thing this issue is intermittent. We can't reproduce it and we don't know next time which icon will be distorted.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have added Xaml and code behind

Comment: Does the image in the listview?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes they are in list.

Comment: I tried above code. but I could not reproduce this issue, could you provide mini sample for us with github?